# Opening multiple files in do loop

Tags: files-and-directories

I'm running a code over different parameter values in mathematica using do loop. I want to open separate files for each parameter within the code itself using loop and write output corresponding to each parameter value into separate files. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Where are you stuck? Notice that nothing even indicates that it is about Wolfram Mathematica. Please read [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: When I use do loop for OpenWrite command as                                              Do[OpenWrite["m.dat"];
  Close[m], {m, 1, 2}];                                                                                       It is giving error as 1 is not string

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What do you mean by `Close[1]`? Please edit the question with the code.

Comment: I want to do something like this                                                                                                                 Do[pth = OpenWrite["file_i.dat"];
 Do [Write[pth, n^2], {n, {4, 5}}];
 Close[pth], {i, 1, 2}]                                                                                        I want output corresponding to n=4 to be written in file named file_1.dat and output corresponding to n=2 in file_2.dat

Comment: StringJoin + ToString presented in linked topics is the way to go for you. Let me know if you disagree.